# Getting Array Input From Command Line

Tags: c

I am using the command line to get input of 3 **floats** separated by spaces. e.g. `"1.234 5.678 9.012"`.

I am currently using:

```
float xyz[3] = {0};
scanf("%f", xyz);
print(%f %f %f, xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2]);
```

However the output is "`1.234000 0.000000 0.000000`".

Expected output is "`1.234000 5.678000 9.012000`"

**EDIT: I need to use floats instead of integers.**

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: @Roecrew see my edit above

Comment: What is scant? Do you mean scanf?

Comment: Yeah. Autocorrect...

Comment: Well you probably want something more like this...scanf("%f", &array[0]);

Comment: I want the whole line to input as xyz[0] [1] and [2] in one go. Is this possible?

Comment: Read up on pointers and arrays. http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm

Comment: you are scanning a single float and printing 3 floats. try looping the scanf() thrice and look for the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float vals[3];

    printf("input 3 float values: ");
    int res = scanf("%f %f %f", &vals[0], &vals[1], &vals[2]);

    if(res == 3)
    {
        printf("read 3 floats %f %f %f\n", vals[0], vals[1], vals[2]);

    } else
    {
        printf("failed to read 3 float values\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this line: if(res >= 0) fails to assure that 3 items were read.  The line should be: if(res == 3)

Answer (score 2):

If you use command line arguments , simply try like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main(int c, char **v)
{

float xyz[3]={0};

xyz[0]=atof(v[1]);
xyz[1]=atof(v[2]);
xyz[2]=atof(v[3]);

printf("%f %f %f\n",xyz[0],xyz[1],xyz[2]);

}
```

Comment: this is correct for what the OP stated they were actually doing.

Comment: This should check that c (conventionally argc) is at least 3 before proceeding with the atof calls, if its less than 3 segfault. @user3629249 I disagree that this is more in line with what the OP stated they were actually doing, they said they were using scanf.